# HybridAuth not giving the user email, age or language

Tags: php, facebook, hybridauth

I am following this tutorial on [HybridAuth Faceboook Authentication](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/IDProvider_info_Facebook.html).

But it only gives me the displayname field. Other fields are empty and null. Why is that and how can I get their values?

```
object(Hybrid_User_Profile)#10 (24) { ["identifier"]=> string(16) "148108450885555" ["webSiteURL"]=> string(0) "" ["profileURL"]=> string(0) "" ["photoURL"]=> string(72) "https://graph.facebook.com/1481084508875555/picture?width=150&height=150" ["displayName"]=> string(17) "User Name" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["firstName"]=> string(0) "" ["lastName"]=> string(0) "" ["gender"]=> string(0) "" ["language"]=> string(0) "" ["age"]=> NULL ["birthDay"]=> NULL ["birthMonth"]=> NULL ["birthYear"]=> NULL ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["emailVerified"]=> string(0) "" ["phone"]=> NULL ["address"]=> NULL ["country"]=> NULL ["region"]=> string(0) "" ["city"]=> NULL ["zip"]=> NULL ["username"]=> string(0) "" ["coverInfoURL"]=> string(269) "https://graph.facebook.com/1481084508878224?fields=cover&access_token=CAAVE8ueaRqUBAMXgmDAVCPbNvMdJfDNMWfJNhnf5M9laaGlZCyVKoa4DcnsbkmoFqTImZBsfZAgHIh4fNEwxATQ9JJ6aDk8nUJKRCOVBJuEaxDkSDciSkm0ZA1dCMxm4wZAInZAZC01E6H6DaRCUysPN2fuNf7tZAt00ZCYKcDoVeBfIFIEsZD" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook email problem has solved after updating **/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid** folder with new version.

[Download Latest Version](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/releases)